# How do I delete posts to my Facebook Group that are links from another user's Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

I administer a Facebook that is mainly about members posting and commenting on photos.  Most members go the group wall and post photos directly to the group gallery. If a post is inappropriate, as admin I can remove it.

However, some members, instead of posting directly to my group, have instead shared photos to my group from albums on their own page.

I am unable to delete those posts from my page.  At the bottom right of their post, where it would normally offer "remove this photo" as one of the admin options I see only "Download" and "Report/Remove Tag" as my options.

Even removing the posters from the group and blocking them did not remove their shared photos. I can't believe that I am unable to remove content from my own group but so far I can't find any way to get rid of these shared posts. Can anyone help?

Comment: Perhaps this helps: http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=147892458617967#How-do-I-remove-posts-by-group-members?

Answer (score 1):

At the top right of photo posts on a group wall, there is a down-arrow that has 4 options under it - Delete Post, Delete & Remove User, Hide Post, and Report.

Clicking Delete is supposed to work, but occasionally with Facebook glitches, it remains visible to everyone else in the group.

'Hide Post' will not delete the photo from the albums, but it will stop showing on the group wall.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with a spammer.  Turns out he create a photo album on the group site and put his spam pictures in there.  To get rid of it, go to the photos section of your group page,  find the album with the spam,  and delete it.